# How do I change my WordPress language in an if condition?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies, plugins

I've saved the language cookies like this:

```
function aws_set_language_cookie() {

    //To save the language in a cookie
    
    $current_language = get_locale();
    
    if ($current_language == "es_ES") {
        $result = setcookie('lang', $current_language, time() + (30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS), '/');


    } else {
        $result = setcookie('lang', $current_language, time() + (30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS), '/');
    }

    //To read the cookie and change the language based on the cookie
    
    if (isset($_COOKIE['lang']) && $_COOKIE['lang'] == "es_ES") {
        //need code to change website language to spanish here
    }
}
```

How do I change the language to Spanish inside the last if statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
 /* you have not mention that your code written with which hook but there is one hook available to change language run time in wordpress */ 
/* please try you code with below hook function */
```

add_filter( 'locale', 'set_my_locale' );

```
    function set_my_locale( $lang ) { 
        if ( isset($_COOKIE['lang']) && $_COOKIE['lang'] == "es_ES") {   
            return 'es_ES'; 
        } else { 
           // return original language 
       }
     }
```